# Pick the values from specific lines of a log file and calculate an average

Tags: python, loops

guys, 
i have a log file that looks like this

```
Input image filename:(416, 416, 3)
Found 3 boxes for img
Inference time : 3.100685347104464 
traffic light 0.85 
traffic light 0.96 
traffic light 0.98 
Input image filename:(416, 416, 3)
Found 3 boxes for img
Inference time : 2.0816197767817197 
traffic light 0.90 
traffic light 0.92 
Input image filename:(416, 416, 3)
Found 3 boxes for img
Inference time : 2.0610929683485253 
traffic light 0.82 
traffic light 0.96 
traffic light 0.99
```

I want to write a loop that adds the values of traffic light between the lines "Inference time .." and "Input image filename .." together and calculates the average.  
for example :  
for the first part: (0.85+0.96+0.98)/3 = 0.93  
for the second part: (0.90+0.92)/2 = 0.91  
for the third part: (0.82+0.96+0.99)/3 = 0.93

Returned value: (0.93, 0.91, 0.93)

So far, I could only read all values in the line where the words traffic light are found.

```py
import os 
log_path  = "data/test.log"

accuracy_lines = []
accuracy = [] 

for line_acc in open(log): 
    if 'traffic light ' in line_acc: 
        accuracy_lines.append(line_acc)

for n in range(len(accuracy_lines)):
    lineParts = accuracy_lines[n].split(',')
    accuracy.append(float(lineParts[0].split()[2]))
print(accuracy)
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to continue. 
I would be pleased if you could help me.

Many greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
log_path  = "data/test.log"

with open(log_path) as f:
    numbers, res = [], []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('traffic light'):
            numbers.append(float(line.split()[-1]))
        elif line.startswith('Input image filename') and numbers:
            res.append(sum(numbers) / (len(numbers)))
            numbers.clear()
    if numbers: res.append(sum(numbers) / len(numbers))  # capturing trailing numbers
    print(res)
```

The output:

```
[0.93, 0.91, 0.9233333333333332]
```